# Comparing two excel sheets in same worksheet, and matching the rows to see if they both have the same data

Tags: excel, function, match, vlookup, worksheet

This may sound confusing, so I will do my best to explain what I mean.

I have 2 tabs in my excel worksheet, and both SHOULD have the same data for employees, dates, names etc... but because there is that much data, it would take miles to long to manually go through each row and column and compare all the rows to check that they match.

The question I have is, if possible..

Is there a way I can lookup a whole row in one excel tab, and then see if all the data in that row matches any of the rows in the other worksheet, and if so, highlight the row green? Or if they do not match, then highlight the whole row Red?

I am new to using excel and I am at a loss as to whether this is something I can do. I have looked into INDEX, VLOOKUP and MATCH and can't work out whether any of those should be used.

If this question is a little too vague or if you need me to explain what I mean in more detail I will do so.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is indeed a little too vague, but if the data should be EXACTLY the same, what you can do is:

1. In each Sheet, create a new column called "KEY", and in Sheet 1, a new column called "MATCH?"
2. In "KEY" you concatenate all the values of the other columns in the same row, for example: `=CONCAT(A2:Z2)`
3. In "MATCH?" you use VLOOKUP to search for the same key in the other sheet.

Example:

```
=VLOOKUP(AA2, Sheet2!AA:AA, 1, 0)
```

Then you can do conditional formating to highlight 1 in green and 0 in red.

Hope this helps.